# MUI TextField: hide label but support accessibility and testing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

MUI TextField says you need to include a `label` for Accessibility: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#accessibility

However, this changes the layout of the page. I don't want a label floating above the TextField.

I've tried

```
InputLabelProps={{sx: { display: "none" },}}
```

but this doesn't fix the layout. The label is invisible but still taking up layout space.

I've also tried using only `aria-label` instead of `label`, but that doesn't create an accessible name for use with react testing library, nor does VoiceOver use it as the first thing it says, like if it's a proper A11y name.

Finally, I tried the `name` field on the TextArea, and that doesn't work either.

```
<TextField
  variant="standard"
  value="sample"
  label="thought title"
  name="thought title"
/>
```

Comment: Try passing `display:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do something like:
`InputLabelProps={{sx: { display: "none" },}}` and then to solve the space issue pass a space character to the `helperText` prop:

```
<TextField
  helperText="Please enter your name"
  id="demo-helper-text-aligned"
  label="Name"
/>
<TextField
  helperText=" "
  id="demo-helper-text-aligned-no-helper"
  label="Name"
/>
```

Check out this link
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#helper-text